# Plot Multiple Y axis + 'hue' from Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, plot

**Hello World**,

Below is an example of my df

```
df
Date       Name   x1  x2  x3  x4
01/01/16   aa     10  15  20  11
01/01/16   bb     10  10  50  14
02/01/16   aa     12  30  17  25
02/01/16   bb     17  10  14  25
```

...

**Question:**

How can I plot on:

- x-axis the date
- y-axis x1,x2,x3, x4
- **hue Name**

What I have done so far, gives me the following output

```
g= df.plot(x="date", y=['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'], figsize=(30,10), kind='bar')
```

[image]

The expected output will be the same as above but with the Name as title. 
I thought of hue argument like in seaborn but not working with pandas.plot

Thanks for everyone helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with dataframe melt as per J.K., some chart options:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.barplot(x="Date", y='values', hue='Name', data=df, ci=None)

sns.catplot(data=df, x='Date', y='values', hue='Name', kind="bar", ci=None)
```

the ci removes the confidence interval draw if you do not need it

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your dataframe:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=['Date', 'Name'], value_name='values', 
var_name='variables')

sns.catplot(data=df, x='Date', y='values', hue='variables', col='Name', 
kind="bar")
```